# Adding up columns in a CSV file to a distinct Key

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file that has numerous rows and columns.  All rows will be distinct except for the first column which will be an account name.  There are for example ten different account names that have about 100 rows for each account name . So for each account name that appears I need to get a sum for all the proceeding columns in that row.

So a csv file like this:

Smith, 10, 5, 9

Smith, 9, 5, 6

Jones, 10, 5, 7

jones, 9, 6, 5

Needs to be written to another file like this:

Smith, 19, 19, 15

Jones, 19, 11, 12

Been trying all morning using either an array or a Dictionary to do this, but I can't seem to logically get this done.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String path = @"C:\Users\jhochbau\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CsvReader\CsvReader\Position_2016_02_25.0415.csv";

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            string[] parsedLine = line.Split(',');
            //for each iteration through the loop where string[0] is already existing
            //I want to have sum = sum + string[1]
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

I also tried using a dictionary for this but ended up only grabbing the row when a distinct name came up.

```
//To add account as key and each line as value
foreach(var s in data)
{
    string[] temp = s.Split(',');
    //Adds key of account into dictionary, full string line as value.
    dictionary.Add(temp[0], temp);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> accountKeyValuePair in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account = {}", accountKeyValuePair.Key);   //Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
    }
}
```

Looking for either a link to a similar example, or maybe a gentle nudge in the right logical direction.  I don't really want the answer coded for me.

Comment: are you familiar with `Control Break` processing.. you can do this by creating a class that mimic's the csv file structure.. then when you read all of the data into a string[] you can do a while loop checking that the account names are equal ..when they do not.. then do your calculation and set the new account name equal to the previous for example while account name not equal to the first read initializing the account name = to `string.Empty` read the first name.. and sent the account variable = first value which will be `Smith` next read or string[] postition 0 will equal smith. .. 3rd won't

Comment: then you do your calculation... etc... there are numerous ways to do this.. if you draw it out you will see just how easy it it.. also you can sum values of an string[] using `Linq along with the Skip()` function

Comment: I was thinking of creating a class to mimic the CSV file.  But for some reason thought there would be an easier way.  So I will go ahead and do that. Thank you for confirming my suspicion.

Comment: ok, so guess I would need a pseudo code example of trying to compare parsedLine[0], to positions.account., and break from that loop when they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
public static void Run()
        {
            var lines = new List<string>() { 
            "Smith, 10, 5, 9",
            "Smith, 9, 5, 6",
            "Jones, 10, 5, 7",
            "Jones, 9, 6, 5"
            };


            var aList = from l in lines                        
                        select new { Name = l.Split(',')[0], Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(l.Split(',')[1]), Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(l.Split(',')[2]), Value3 = Convert.ToInt32(l.Split(',')[3]) };

            var vList = from a in aList
                        group a by a.Name into g
                        select new { Name = g.Key, Value1Sum = g.Sum(a => a.Value1), Value2Sum = g.Sum(a => a.Value2), Value3Sum = g.Sum(a => a.Value3) };

            foreach (var v in vList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", v.Name, v.Value1Sum, v.Value2Sum, v.Value3Sum);
        }
```