# Iterate through array and add up elements with a control break logic

Tags: c#, iteration, break

I am trying to use this  for each loop to iterate through this array, and sum up the elements, 12, 10, 8, 7, and 6, when element 0 is not different (position.account), using control break logic,

This is furthering on a [question I had earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706681/adding-up-columns-in-a-csv-file-to-a-distinct-key), but I can't seem to figure out how to do this logically.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String path = @"C:\Users\jhochbau\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CsvReader\CsvReader\Position_2016_02_25.0415.csv";

        //Adding lines read into a string[];
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            Positions position = new Positions();
            string[] parsedLine = line.Split(',');

            position.account = parsedLine[0];
            position.settleMM = parsedLine[10];
            position.open = parsedLine[6];
            position.buy = parsedLine[7];
            position.sell = parsedLine[8];
            position.underlying = parsedLine[12];
            //Need to convert these to an int.

            //for each iteration through the loop where string[0] is already existing
            //I want to have sum = sum + string[10]
        }

        Console.Read();
    }   

    public class Positions
    {
        public string account { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string prevClose { get; set; }
        public string curPrx { get; set; }
        public string settlePX { get; set; }
        public string Mult { get; set; }
        public string open { get; set; }
        public string buy { get; set; }
        public string sell { get; set; }
        public string netMM { get; set; }
        public string settleMM { get; set; }
        public string settleDay { get; set; }
        public string underlying { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like there's several questions here, are you trying to figure out how to check if the `account` has already been summed up?  Or how to parse the values in the array into integers that can be summed up?

Comment: Store the `Positions` objects you create in some dictionary or array outside the for loop. Within the for loop check check if the account number exists in the array. If it does just add up it's corresponding values, else add it as a new element to the array.

Comment: Sorry, if my post wasn't specific.  To clarify I am stuck trying to think of a way to create a while loop on the condition that the while loop breaks when position.account is not the same as the previous iteration.  The link I provided from my previous question gives an example of the output I am looking for.

Comment: I have no issues converting to an Int, I could manage that part.  @JamesBuck was hitting at my issue here.

Comment: One sum for each account or only one sum in total for a specific account?

Comment: one sum for each acount

Comment: Then go for a `Dictionary<string,double>` (or `int` or `decimal`) outside the loop and simply add up... put an account in the dictionary the first time it shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, you could do something like this:

```
// store the accounts inside this dictionary
var accounts = new Dictionary<string, Positions>();
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Positions position = new Positions();
    string[] parsedLine = line.Split(',');

    position.account = parsedLine[0];
    ...

    Positions existingAccount;
    // if the account already exists in the dictionary
    if (accounts.TryGetValue(position.account, out existingAccount)) {
        existingAccount.buy += position.buy;
        // do updating logic here
    } else {
        accounts.add(position.account, position);
        // otherwise add it as a new element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could go for Linq:

```
File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select( line => new Position(line) )
    .GroupBy( position => position.account )
    .Select( group => new { Account = group.Key,
                            Sum = group.Select( position => position.settleMM ).Sum() } );
```

Comment: Just be careful not to parse the file too often - if you need the positions more than once, add a `ToList` after the first `Select` and store it somewhere.

Comment: since you mentioned parsing earlier, for some reason the tryParse method isn't working.

position.settleMM = int.TryParse(parsedLine[10]);

Giving me an error of no overloading method.

Comment: Because you get the result by means of an `out` parameter (it's `public static bool TryParse( string s, out int result )`, from msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)